# what is the correct path to load a local html file to an intent in Android?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, load, local

I have a web site made of static local files that I am trying to load into an intent.  It uses JavaScript, so I am under the impression I have to use an intent instead of a webview.

The file is located at "assets/site_files/index.html".
This is the code I am trying to use:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/site_files/index.html");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, path);
startActivity(intent);
```

The app crashes while starting the Intent, with this as the last entry in the console:

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent
```

The app works fine if I load the site on a web server instead of trying to load a local version.  The following works perfectly:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("http://www.domain.com/test_app_static/index.html");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, path);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I need it to run locally so users can run it without an internet connection.
I have looked around and tried several different solutions, but none of them worked for me in the specific situation of loading a local html file into an intent.  Please help!

Comment: file:///android_asset/site_files/index.html path correct for locally run

Comment: why do you wanna use an Intent and not a WebView? WebView works fine with local HTML files using JavaScript (even if the JavaScript is in an external file in the same folder)

Comment: Thank you!  That loaded the file and then worked once I enabled JavaScript for the WebView.

Answer (score 1):

The correct url is `file:///android_asset/site_files/index.html`. The reason the app may be crashing is due to the fact that the `asset` files can only be accessed by your app. Therefore you are going to need to display that data in a `WebView`.

Comment: SquiresSquire, that worked with the WebView.  I am still working out some scaling issues, but I am on the way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the index.html page to your app data(`data/data/<your.package>`) folder. You can get the location using the api [Activity.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), and pass [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) as the argument so that other applications can read the file from your app data folder. Now you can pass this path as part of the `intent`. Remember other applications can't access your `assets` folder.